# vb6 date arithmetic and the vb.net equivalent

Tags: vb.net, datetime, vb6, vb6-migration

I have inherited the following code in `vb6`:

```
Dim countDate As Date

countDate = Date - 1
```

Does this subtract a day from the `countDate` variable or something completely different?

Also if I wanted to change this into vb.net then what would the equivalent be?

Comment: `countDate = Date - 1` wont compile because Date is a Type.  `countDate=countDate.AddDays(-1)`

Comment: If I remember correctly, you used the `DateAdd` function to manipulate dates in VB 6. I don't know if the arithmetic operators were overloaded or not, but like has already been said, `Date` is a type, not an object, so this won't compile. If you wanted to get the current date, you'd use something like `DateValue(Now)`.

Comment: This is what I thought, However this is in code that I have been given from a working application running on a live server. Is there any weird magic that would make this compile somehow?

Comment: Well, I think VB 6 used to allow you to create objects with the same name as their type. So maybe there's some `Date` variable somewhere? Yay, global variables! Try your editor's Find feature.

Comment: Awesome, i'll have a look, thanks. For some context this program was made by a guy paid by the hour who seemed to enjoy make classes for the hell of it to fill time. so I wouldn't be surprised if there's something weird going on!

Comment: The VB6 Date function returns the current date, same as Now.Date.  Subtracting 1 produces the previous day.  So it is Dim countDate = Now.Date.AddDays(-1)

Comment: oh so it would compile? if you put that as an answer i'll accept it

Comment: @JabbaWook- Hans Passant is right: VB6 did very smart date operations ... more intuitiv then adding negativ values to a datetime type ...

Comment: @all vb6-haters: Yes, VB6 was not THAT bad ...

Comment: @nabuchodonossor IS not ...